# SQL Server display the count of consecutive failures

Tags: sql-server

I need to be able to retrieve the number of consecutive failures for each region and channel based on this sample table:

```
id   reportdate             region  channel fail1   fail2
1   2017-05-22 00:00:00.000 canada  A   True    False
3   2017-05-23 00:00:00.000 canada  A   True    False
4   2017-05-24 00:00:00.000 canada  A   False   True
5   2017-05-25 00:00:00.000 canada  A   True    True
6   2017-05-25 00:00:00.000 canada  B   True    True
```

Each time I receive a False, then the counter resets.  Using this stored procedure, I am able to display the number of consecutive failures for each region, channel for fail1 but I can not figure out how I include fail2 in the results.

```
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Insert statements for procedure here
SELECT
    region, channel, MAX(reportDate),
    COUNT(*) AS consecutive_errors
FROM
    dfc_test t1
WHERE
    NOT EXISTS
    (
        SELECT * FROM dfc_test t2
        WHERE t2.region = t1.region
        AND t2.channel = t1.channel
        AND t2.reportDate >= t1.reportDate
        AND t2.fail1 = 0

    )
GROUP BY
    region, channel
HAVING
    MAX(reportDate) = MAX(CASE WHEN fail1 = 1 THEN reportDate END)
```

My current result set is this and I need it to show error counts for both types:

```
region  channel (No column name)    consecutive_errors
canada  A   2017-05-25 00:00:00.000 1
canada  B   2017-05-25 00:00:00.000 1
```

Need the result to look like this:

```
region  channel (No column name)    fail1_errors fail2_errors
canada  A   2017-05-25 00:00:00.000 1            2
canada  B   2017-05-25 00:00:00.000 1            1
```

Comment: how fail2_errors calculated?

Comment: Why would Channel A have 2 fail2 errors but only 1 fail1 error?   Why does Channel B have any fail errors?   There is only one Channel B row, so it can't be consecutive with any other.

Comment: Your hung up on the sample output.  I am just trying to show that there are two entirely different error conditions that I need to report if there are consecutive errors.  I can get the first one to work correctly, just not the second one using the same logic.

Comment: is your sample output accurate according to your sample data? seems like I can't get the logic. If not, kindly update expected output according to your sample data.

Comment: The actual sample output is from running the stored procedure.  The one that I need is mocked up but accurate.